# How to parse this x509 SSL/TLS certificate format?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, tls1.2, pyopenssl

I have a certificate format (the strings between -`----END CERTIFICATE----- and BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`) that look like this saved in `json` format:

> {     "af":6,     "cert":     [       "-----BEGIN
>   CERTIFICATE-----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\nstR8lihH\n-----END
>   CERTIFICATE-----",        "-----BEGIN
>   CERTIFICATE-----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\ncPUeybQ=\n-----END
>   CERTIFICATE-----"     ],  "dst_addr":"2001:67c:2e8:22::c100:68b",
>     "dst_name":"www.ripe.net",  "dst_port":"443",
>     "from":"2001:67c:2e8:ffe2:220:4aff:fec6:cc9d",  "fw":4790,  "lts":58,
>     "method":"TLS",     "msm_id":15001,     "msm_name":"SSLCert",   "prb_id":9,
>     "rt":22.177541,     "src_addr":"2001:67c:2e8:ffe2:220:4aff:fec6:cc9d",
>     "timestamp":1503448834,     "ttc":4.284673,     "type":"sslcert",
>     "ver":"1.2" }

I use python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.

My question is:

How can I extract the certificate fields such as subject name, issuer, certificate fingerprint, etc. from the above format?

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is not a coding service. Please show what you've tried and where you failed. Hint: the `cert` part of the JSON seems to contain a list of certificates in PEM format. You can load such a PEM string into a certificate object with [OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate) and then you get access to the certificate details.